# Query Appcelerator Cloud services Place with LIKE operator and case insensitive

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, sql-like

**Q) Is it possible to query Appcelerator cloud services Places objects (insensitive) where: - name LIKE 'fred' - SQL would be something like?**

```
SELECT * FROM Places WHERE name like '%fred%'
```

I.e. query would return (if existing):

- Fred
- Alfred
- Winnefred

**Please tell me if this is possible with a simple code block using Ti.Cloud or REST or anything!**

Note: I've read the documentation thoroughly but can't find an answer there. Please don't direct me to the documentation for the answer. Thanks.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly. What you want is a $regex in the "where" parameter of Places.Query. The docs say it only supports prefix searches, but maybe it can do more. The below would be the equivalent of your select.

```
Ti.Cloud.Places.query({
    where: {
        name: { $regex: 'fred', $options: 'i' }
    }
}, ...);
```

If it doesn't work, then you'll need to open up a feature request for it.

http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/places/query
http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/search_query

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dawson. Unfortunately, it's only prefix which is useless. I decided a couple of days ago to ditch their crippled cloud services and just write my own WCF service hooked onto a modified cms I wrote a while back. It's a little more work sure, but the result is I get what I actually want i.e a proper search algorithm and any extra functionality I want without having to fudge through someone else's poorly written API!

Comment: It seems like a bit of a leap to describe it as "fudging through" a "poorly written API" because one feature you want isn't currently present (unless you're harboring other hurts without letting on). Appc has a ticket for adding regex support to ACS, so it'll come in the future. Glad to see you got something working, though.